# Button PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

i have 3 button i want when i click button 1, hide that button and show all button with PlayerPrefs, and when i click button 2, hide that button and show all button with PlayerPrefs i test my code  but work with button 2 only

```
void Start()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Button1") == 1)
    {
        object1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        object2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Button1") == 0)
    {
        object1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        object2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }


    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Button2") == 1)
    {
        object2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        object1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Button2") == 0)
    {
        object1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        object2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
public void whenclickbutton1()
{
    object2.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Button1", 1); PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Button2", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();

}
public void whenclickbutton2()
{

    object1.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Button2", 1); PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Button1", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Comment: You should put the conditional functions in Update()

Comment: when i put conditional into update a first  button can't Hide when i click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want to hide the clicked button, and show the rest?
Only having 1 playerpref would work then, containing the hidden button?

```
void Start()
{
    HideAndShowButtons();
}
void HideAndShowButtons()
{
    object1.gameObject.SetActive(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HiddenButton") != 1);
    object2.gameObject.SetActive(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HiddenButton") != 2);
}

public void whenclickbutton1()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HiddenButton", 1);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    HideAndShowButtons();
}
public void whenclickbutton2()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HiddenButton", 2);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    HideAndShowButtons();
}
```